# Updated file in jar creates absolute path, cannot find the path specified

Tags: java, jar, archive

I've been racking my brains about this. I want to replace an image file inside a jar. The image is located in images/logo.png (according to jar tf). I used "jar vfu test.jar images/" to update the file. Output...

```
jar vfu test.jar images/
adding: images/(in = 0) (out= 0)(stored 0%)
adding: images/logo.png(in = 2435) (out= 2419)(deflated 0%)
```

If I run the jar from that location the update works, I see the new logo. But when I try to run the jar from some other location other than where I updated it, I get a file not found exception showing the absolute path of the image: c:\temp\images\logo.png.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\temp\images\logo.png (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

What am I doing wrong here?